# Nuclear physics notation

Tags: nuclear-physics, notation, term-symbols

This is probably a very basic question about notation. If we have the following notation for Boron nuclei:

$$^{12}_5 B(1^+)\;\text{or}\; ^{10}_3B(3^+)$$

What does the number in the parentheses mean? I guess $1$ and $3$ correspond to a spin number and $\pm$ to the parity. But what spin is that exactly and how do you find it?

Comment: Minor comment (v2): presumably $\rm^{10}_3B$ is boron-10 with the proton number typo’d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the nuclear spin or the total angular momentum. See [Possible spins and parities of $^{38}_{17}Cl$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483032/possible-spins-and-parities-of-38-17cl?rq=1)

Comment: Correct. [This database confirms](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat3/indx_sigma.jsp) to confirms those are the ground-state $J^\pi$ for boron-12 and boron-10.

Comment: @GeorgePhys: please accept this answer, if it helps you